# How to get a branch name with a slash in Azure DevOps?

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops

Azure Devops offers two variables containing information about the current git branch name: `$(Build.SourceBranchName)` and `$(Build.SourceBranch)`.

While `SourceBranch` contains the full reference to the branch, `SourceBranchName` is expected to contain only the short branch name.

Unfortunately, the behavior is a bit unexpected when the branch name contains a slash (`/`):

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Situation                     | Git branch name  | Build.SourceBranch          | Build.SourceBranchName |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| branch name contains no slash | mybranch         | refs/heads/mybranch         | mybranch               |
| branch name contains slash    | release/mybranch | refs/heads/release/mybranch | mybranch               |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The part of the branch name before the slash is not considered as part of the branch name. My colleague pointed out that this is the [documented behavior of Azure Devops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml):

> Git repo branch or pull request: The last path segment in the ref. For example, in refs/heads/master this value is master. In refs/heads/feature/tools this value is tools.

I am not sure if this behavior is particularly useful: I want to checkout the branch, and need the branch name to *include* the slash. Also, If the part before the slash is stripped off, there might well be confusion about the actual path, as the name could be ambiguous.

I need the branch name *including* the slash. Is there any simple way to get it? Do I always have to work with the full ref in order to be on the safe side?

Comment: It is so hard to decide which one is more correct lol

Comment: Hi hey thanks for your kindly response. Both reply is ok, same concept just with different implementation. You could choose one more apply to your situation. Up to you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you build on a PR, you could use  `System.PullRequest.SourceBranch` and `System.PullRequest.TargetBranch` variables.

> *System.PullRequest.TargetBranch*
>
> The branch that is the target of a pull request. For example:
>   `refs/heads/master`. This variable is initialized only if the build
>   ran because of a Git PR affected by a branch policy.

[Use Predefined Build Variables](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/variables)

Besides, you could also define your own variable based on your needs if you want to use full or short path.

Just create a bash script that assigns the shorter branch name to a variable.

```
# Bash script
BRANCH_NAME=$(echo "$(System.PullRequest.TargetBranch)" | awk -F/ '{print $NF}')
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PullRequest_Target_Branch;]$BRANCH_NAME"
```

Then you could reference $(PullRequest_Target_Branch) in your pipeline later.

Answer (score 50):

You can use [replace expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#replace) to remove `refs/heads/` from `Build.SourceBranch`

```yaml
  variables:
    BRANCH_NAME: $[replace(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/', '')]
```

Use like this *(edited typo)*

```
$(BRANCH_NAME)
```

Comment: Yes, but you must use `Build.SourceBranch` !!! The var in your example `SourceBranchName` only returns the last path segment in the ref.

Comment: Aside from the error that @Chris pointed out, this should be the accepted answer

Comment: Heads up, the answer assumes the trigger is a _branch_ and not a _tag_

Answer (score 35):

I always use `Build.SourceBranch` in my scripts. Just assign it to a new variable and remove `refs/heads/` from the start. I use only for CI and PR:

1. For CI. I use `Build.SourceBranch` variable without `refs/heads`. I work with PowerShell:

> $branchSource = "$(Build.SourceBranch)"
>   $branchSourcePath = $branchSource -replace "refs/heads/", ""

2. For PRs. I use `System.PullRequest.SourceBranch` variable without `refs/heads` because `Build.SourceBranch` contains the path to the remote PR. The replacement is the same as in the first option just use the right variable.

> $branchSource = "$(System.PullRequest.SourceBranch)"
>   $branchSourcePath = $branchSource -replace "refs/heads/", ""

Comment: Do you have some additional logic for cases where you build on a PR or a tag?

Answer (score 7):

It's wild there is no proper solution to this yet.

Here is what we have, based on combining a few things I've found googling. This is for branches and PR's

```
variables:

  ${{ if startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/') }}:
    BRANCH_NAME: $[ replace(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/', '') ]
    DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG: $[ replace(replace(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/', ''), '/', '_') ]

  ${{ if startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/pull/') }}:
    BRANCH_NAME: $[ replace(variables['System.PullRequest.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/', '') ]
    DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG: $[ replace(replace(variables['System.PullRequest.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/', ''), '/', '_') ]
```

`BRANCH_NAME` will include the slash. So `refs/heads/mybranch` will be `mybranch` but `refs/heads/feature/mybranch` will be `feature/mybranch`.

Also added `DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG` here as we needed to replace the `/` with `_` for docker images tags

Comment: One year later an there is still no better solution. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: my guess is that it's triggered by a tag your also going to want to deal with `refs/tags/`

Answer (score 0):

Can be used below in the azure-pipelines.yml

```
branch=$(Build.SourceBranch)
export branch=$(echo "${branch}" | sed 's/refs\/heads\///g')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a same needs, but I need to get the branch name in a bash script and run the script. Here is what I come up with:

```bash
# remove the "refs/heads/" part from the branch name
branch_name=${BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH#"refs/heads/"}
```

Notice that the predefined variable `any.variable` will be turned to env variable `ANY_VARIABLE` in the shell environment (source [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#access-variables-through-the-environment)). So the pre-defined variable `Build.SourceBranch` becomes `BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH` in bash script.

Comment: Note that the double-quote here is superfluous, and possibly confusing. This is called [parameter substitution](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) and exists in many different flavors. If you trigger on something that's not a branch, say a tag where the `BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH` starts with `refs/tags/` then you're going to have to handle that differently

Comment: to handle more than just `refs/heads/` you should be able to use `refs/*/` in the substitution instead