# Get feature branch name in Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-tasks

trying to build an Android project, gradle checkout the specific branch that was triggered by Azure DevOps and build the package. After task finish Azure Pipelines checkout to HEAD. As a result, in the next task when i get branch name/tag, doesn't print the branch name(feature/**Android_fix_something**). I would like to rename apk file with name of tag(**Android_fix_something.apk**).

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/q/59956206/6064933

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for `Build.SourceBranchName`:

> **Build.SourceBranchName**
>
> The name of the branch in the triggering repo the build was queued for.
>
> Git repo branch or pull request: The last path segment in the ref. For example, in refs/heads/master this value is master. In refs/heads/feature/tools this value is tools.

[From the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?ampltables=yaml&view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, the Android_fix_something is the tag name of the commit.

If your pipeline is not directly triggered by the commit tag, I am afraid that there is no such predefined variable to get this value.

To get the tag name , you can try the following PowerShell script to get it and set it as the pipeline variable.

```
- powershell: |
   $tag = git describe --exact-match $(Build.SourceVersion)
   
   echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=tagname;]$tag"
   
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script'
```

Then you can use the variable `$(tagname)` in the next tasks.