# Get the branch that triggered the pipeline in azure pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I've an azure yaml based pipeline that has a CI trigger with a branch pattern filter. How can I get the name of the branch that has triggered the pipeline?

Pipeline looks like this -

```
parameters:
- name: TargetBranch
  displayName: Target Branch
  type: string
  default: main


resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: <reponame>
    type: git
    name: <reponname>
    ref: refs/heads/main

trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - es/branchtype1/*

pool: 
<rest of the yml here that requires the branch name that triggered the pipeline>
```

There can be many branches with es/branchtype1/* name(created on daily basis). Whenever there
is a push to any of these branches, this pipeline gets triggered. I need to get the name of the branch on which the push was made.

Comment: As stated below, you should use the build variables. If you want only the name of the branch you will need `$(Build.SourceBranchName)`

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59956206/6064933

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Build variable `Build.SourceBranch`.

> The branch of the triggering repo the build was queued for. Some examples:
>
> - Git repo branch: `refs/heads/master`
> - Git repo pull request: `refs/pull/1/merge`
> - TFVC repo branch: `$/teamproject/main`
> - TFVC repo gated check-in: `Gated_2016-06-06_05.20.51.4369;username@live.com`
> - TFVC repo shelveset build: `myshelveset;username@live.com`
> - When your pipeline is triggered by a tag: `refs/tags/your-tag-name`
>
> When you use this variable in your build number format, the forward slash characters (`/`) are replaced with underscore characters (`_`).
>
> Note: In TFVC, if you are running a gated check-in build or manually building a shelveset, you cannot use this variable in your build number format.

More information: [Use predefined variables - Build variables (DevOps Services)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services)